# Can you use new Date().getMilliseconds() (or a different alternative) as a timer (like setTimeout or setInterval), and if so, how?

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout

I have two setTimeout functions: one makes a div pop up randomly on the y axis, and one moves it vertically. These to need to be perfectly in sync, and setTimeout just doesn't cut it: the div has to reset its x position as soon as its y position becomes greater than the window height, before resetting to 0 to start anew. Something like that. I'm thinking of somehow integrating getMilliseconds, but any alternative will do. 
Here's the current Javascript:

```
var width = window.outerWidth;
var height = window.outerHeight;
var h2 = height * 5;
//left
function LR() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var left = [];
        var one = 1;
        do {
            one++;
            left.push(one);
        }
        while (one <= width);
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * left.length);
        document.getElementById("test").style.left = random + "px";
        LR();
    }, h2);
}
LR();
//top
function TB() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var one = document.getElementById("test").offsetTop;
        one++;
        document.getElementById("test").style.top = one + "px";
        if (one == height) {
            one == 0;
            document.getElementById("test").style.top = 0;
        }
        TB();
    }, 2);
}
TB();
```

If you'd like to look at my full code, and/or preview, I've set up a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JqVb9/. Thanks in advance.

Comment: perform both movements in the same function. You can't guarantee synchronicity without performing both movements from the same timeout event.

Comment: @Jan: That's nearly an answer, so true :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak How would that work out? They both have different timings?

Comment: The line `one++left.push(one)` looks like a syntax error to me (same in `TB()`). What should that be doing?

Comment: Oops, when I imported the code to Stack Overflow, it messed up a bit. All fixed now. What it does is basically makes a range of 1-screen width in pixels in an array, for JavaScript to randomly assign a left style property of one of those values to the div.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for animations you always should check the current time - `setTimeout`/.`Interval` are absolutely unreliable and tend to drift.

To do that, just use `Date.now()` and make your animation a mathematical function to get the position from time (easiest: linear movement).

As @JanDvorak already pointed out in the comments, you should consider performing all movements from the same timer. This will make the animation smoother as you don't change the DOM / styling too often - each frame is usually rendered only once. Also, this will ensure synchronity.